# getting different results when using lambdas and standard python function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lambda, list-comprehension, data-science

[image: review DF (iterated over Json)]i have business_ids as a csv file and a review.json that has business_ids along with other columns. we need to compare and get the reviews that has the same business_ids.

i have retreived business_ids from the csv file and executed it using lambdas. i tried the same using a standard function. the results do not match

Exisitng code: 
Result is [594862 rows x 9 columns] and 
type: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

```
businesses = pd.read_csv('business_list.csv')

review_reader = pd.read_json('review.json', lines=True, chunksize=100000)

business_ids = businesses['business_id'].values


reviews_updated = [review.loc[review['business_id'].apply(lambda x: x in business_ids)] for review in review_reader]

reviews_updated = pd.concat(reviews_updated)
```

My code:
Result is [6884 rows x 9 columns] and 
type is pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

```
for review in review_reader:
    review_business = review


def func(x):
    return x in business_ids

reviews = review_business.loc[review_business['business_id'].apply(func)]
```

i dont know where i am going wrong..

Comment: The functions are identical, but it looks like you are doing two different things with them

Comment: thank you for the reply..could you please eloborate.. i thought they were identical too.. but i dont know why i am getting different result..

also, what needs to be changed to get the desired result..

this will help me understand where i went wrong

Comment: It would be easier to help if you give a sample of your DataFrame... I don't understand why you have a for loop in your code that just assign `review_business`. At the end of this for loop you will just have `review_business` equal to the last `review` in `review_reader` and nothing more would have been done.

Comment: @SmileyProd: i used read_json to read in over 3GB of data into review_reader making it a json object.
so, if i print review reader i get "pandas.io.json.json.JsonReader". 

when i itrate over it, i will get a dataframe (review)...

type(review_business) is a pandas.core.frame.DataFrame..

so i got all the data into a dataframe and then started comparing business_ids..

Comment: @ARC: I understand that you want to iterate over the `review_reader` but when you iterate you just do an assignment and nothing more in your for loop. Maybe you didn't copy paster your whole code but if you did I would suggest you to put more code in your for loop because for now your for loop is equivalent to `review_business = review_header[-1]`. This would be why you have less rows, it is because you only look for data in your last df instead of all your df

Comment: Understood..I created an empty Data Frame and sister appending the review to the DF got the desired output.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
review_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['business_id', 'cool', 'date', 'funny', 'review_id', 'stars', 'text', 'useful', 'user_id'])


for review in review_reader:
    review_df = review_df.append(review)
```